# Fade In / FadeOut angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and would like to know how to do this:

```
$(".change-agency-clicker").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".form").fadeOut(function () {
        $(".agency-change-form").fadeIn();
        $("#agentForm").show();
    });

});
```

So when the user clicks on a button it fadeout a panel and fades in a second panel.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this steps:

1. When the element `.change-agency-clicker` is clicked ([`ngClick`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)), toggle the value of a variable.
2. If this variable is `true`, hide ([`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)) the element `.form`.
3. If this variable is `true`, show ([`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)) the elements `.agency-change-form` and `#agentForm`.
4. Animate all that things with CSS transitions ([here is a tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)), and don't forget `transition-delay` if needed.

The idea, of course, is to think "declarative" and no more "imperative"!

Comment: Yeah I tried that.....it kinda  looks kinda choppy though when in transition  http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: @jberney22 Your plunker is empty.